# replace impl trait return type with trait bound

Tags: rust

Is it possible to change this `impl trait` return type to a trait bound?

```
fn combine_vecs<T: Copy>(v: Vec<T>, u: Vec<T>) -> impl Iterator<Item=T> {
      v.into_iter().chain(u.into_iter()).cycle()
}
```

I tried something like this

```
fn combine_vecs<T: Copy, TI: Iterator<Item=T>>(v: Vec<T>, u: Vec<T>) -> TI {
    v.into_iter().chain(u.into_iter()).cycle()
}
```

but it fails with the following error

```
expected type parameter `TI`
       found struct `Cycle<std::iter::Chain<std::vec::IntoIter<T>, std::vec::IntoIter<T>>>`
```

Not sure why it fails although the struct implements the required trait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't in this specific situation. `impl Trait` does not always have the same meaning.

If it's in the return position of a function declaration, it means "there is a type that implements this trait that is returned by this function". If, instead, you put a generic type `TI: Trait` and returned it, it means "for any type `TI` provided by the caller that implements `Trait`, I can provide a function that returns `TI`".

It's quite clear that in your example, you want the first solution, because the return type of your function is `Cycle<Chain<IntoIter<T>, IntoIter<T>>>`. So the only way to replace the `impl Iterator<Item=T>` would be to specify the concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

```rust
fn foo<T: A>() -> T {...}
fn bar() -> impl A {}
```

In case foo, if someone invokes `foo::<SomeT>()` to determine the return type, things will go wrong if `SomeT` doesn't impl A, because this is above the foo's ability;

In case bar, anyone cannot determine the type returned, everything will be ok.

Above all, there's no need to let user determine the return type, because the ability of the function is fixed. As a result, just use impl is Ok, this prevents error when defining the function instead of when invoking it.